# Java String to int binary number conversion

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert Strings of user input into int. No problem with that, i'm using the following code:

```
c = sc.next();
while(!c.contains("#")){
    i = Integer.parseInt(c);
    input.add(c);
    c= sc.next();
}
```

(this is just the part of the code that does the conversion, the scanner part is working)

The only problem is that the input are binary numbers, so when the input is, for example "00111", the convert gives me "111" and i can't lose those 0's. How can i convert the user input into the number without losing the zeros to the left?

Comment: are these little-endian binary numbers?

Comment: You can't not-lose the zeros and yet be left with a number. It has to be zero-padded string in order to represent that way.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't lose the zeroes?

Comment: Note that in your current code you're not using `i`.

Comment: Why do you want to convent String to int? if you indeed need, for int type it is meaningless to have zeros to the left. Right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `00111` is different from `111` then you can't store it as integers, you'll need to store them as strings.

Note however, that even in binary, 00111<sub>2</sub> is equal to 111<sub>2</sub>.

To parse a binary literal and store it in an integer, you use

```
Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
```

(but this doesn't solve the problem of keeping the leading zeros.)

Comment: As to keep leading zeros, you should use `NumerFormat` class. Something like `formatter = new DecimalFormat("00###");` and then `String result = formatter.format(Integer.parseInt(c, 2));`

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
Integer.parseInt(c, 2)
```

Comment: This would still give the same result for `00111` and `111`.

Comment: @aioobe, sure. But I think the op confusion was with the conversion from binary to decimal. Doing Integer.parseInt("00111") returns 111. This "111" is an Integer represented in base 10 but the op thought it was an Integer represented in base 2.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.parseInt("00111", 2);`

But you have to know the radix in advance to distinguish between binary (2) and decimal (10) numbers.

Or did I perhaps not understand your question? Your statement about "losing 0s" is a little bit difficult to understand.

Comment: This would still give the same result for `00111` and `111`.

Answer (score 0):

To conserve the leading zeros in a binary string s:

From string to integer: append a "1" as prefix to s and translate to integer.

From integer to string: Translate integer to binary string and delete the first "1".